# Executing stored procedures with the help of PHP and SQL Server 2012?

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

I have  developed file upload based on selected dropdown..IT WILL OPEN AND read selected file and based on SQL Server stored procedure content it will insert.

```
// SQL SERVER STORED PROCEDURE
ALTER procedure [dbo].[ITPAN_UPDATE]
(
    @INPUTXML varchar(6000), 
    @UserName varchar(100),
    @PosCode varchar(20),
    @Password varchar(512),
    @UserID bigint,
    @CompanyID bigint,
    @BranchID bigint,       
    @TerminalType Varchar(50),
    @UserType varchar(50),  
    @LOCADD     varchar(20)
)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @AccessQry varchar(max)
    SET     @AccessQry = 'exec ITPAN_UPDATE `' + @INPUTXML + '`'
                         + ',`' + @UserName + '`'
                         + ',`' + @PosCode + '`'
                         + ',`' + @Password + '`'
                         + ', ' + rtrim(convert(char,@UserID)) 
                         + ', ' + rtrim(convert(char,@CompanyID)) 
                         + ', ' + rtrim(convert(char,@BranchID)) 
                         + ',`' + @TerminalType + '`'
                         + ',`' + @UserType + '`'
                         + ',`' + @LOCADD + '`'
    EXEC insUpdtAccessDtlsInterOp @UserName, @PosCode, @LocAdd, @AccessQry

    SET @INPUTXML = REPLACE(@INPUTXML,'e:','\\192.168.22.68')
DECLARE @test varchar(2000) 

SET @test =
             N'BULK INSERT pan_verified FROM ''' + 
             @INPUTXML + 
           N''' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'
          
exec(@test)

insert into testkycdb..New_kyc_details_jrnl
select 0,* from TestkycDB..kyc_details (NOLOCK)
where kyc_status not in ('99','998','999','199','299','399','499','19','801','809','499') and 
 kyc_panno in (select pan_no from  TestkycDB..pan_verified) 

update testkycdb..kyc_details 
set 
kyc_pan_name = pan_name,kyc_pan_verify =COMMENTS
from TestkycDB..pan_verified
where kyc_panno = pan_no
and kyc_status not in ('99','998','999','199','299','399','499','19','801','809','499')

insert into testkycdb..New_kyc_details_jrnl
select * from testkycdb..modified_kyc_details (NOLOCK)
where mod_kyc_status not in ('99','998','999','199','299','399','499','19','801','809','499') and 
 mod_kyc_panno in (select pan_no from TestkycDB..pan_verified) 

update testkycdb..modified_kyc_details 
set 
mod_kyc_pan_name = pan_name,mod_kyc_pan_verify = COMMENTS
from TestkycDB..pan_verified
where mod_kyc_panno = pan_no
and mod_kyc_status not in ('99','998','999','199','299','399','499','19','801','809','499','98')

end
GO
```

// My php code which will open and read file and along with that it will execute stored procedure too

```
$file = fopen("$target_file","r");

while(!feof($file)){
 $content = fgets($file);
 
   $carray = explode(",",$content);
 list($INPUTXML,$UserName,$PosCode,$Password,$UserID,$Password,$UserID,$CompanyID,$BranchID,$TerminalType,$UserType,$LOCADD) = $carray;




  $sql = "{CALL ITPAN_UPDATE (@INPUTXML= ?, @UserName= ?, @PosCode= ?, @Password= ?, @UserID= ?, @CompanyID= ?, @BranchID= ?,@TerminalType= ?,@UserType=?,@LOCADD=?)}";
  
   $params = array( 
    array(&$INPUTXML, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),

    array(&$UserName, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),

    array(&$PosCode, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),


    array(&$Password, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    
    array(&$UserID, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),

    array(&$CompanyID, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    
    array(&$BranchID, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),

    array(&$TerminalType, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),

    array(&$UserType, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),

    array(&$LOCADD, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),


  );

  $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql,$params);
 
if ($result === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

  while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo print_r($row, true);
 }

    if($row===1){
      echo "Stored procedure Executed Succesfully";
    }else{
          echo "Failed Execution";
    }

fclose($file);  
sqlsrv_close($conn);
  }


// I have wrote this code in php which will open and read  .txt file and based on file content it will perform stored procedure action basically which will update or insert 
I am getting below errors and i am unable to figure out the reason behind following errors
feel free to modify my code any help would be highly appreciated ...
```

// ERROR WHICH I AM GETTING IS

> Error (sqlsrv_query): Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 4860 [code] => 4860 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot bulk load. The file "KKKPM7351E" does not exist. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot bulk load. The file "KKKPM7351E" does not exist. ) )

EVEN THOUGH THIS  Content is already stored inside my database ...

Comment: This is unreadable. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and then [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson can you please edit my code even after reading this documentation i am unable to edit my code...

Comment: @ADyson when i tried editing the same it started giving me to add  more context ... and even after adding context it was not letting me post this code

Comment: I must be missing something here... if the content is already stored inside the database why are you trying to bulk insert it again? The SQL Server service runs under a specific Windows user account, does that account have **both** Share and file system permissions to the folders and files inside `\\192.168.22.68\...`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I WANT TO UPDATE  FULL NAME"   MATCHING THIS PAN NO KKKPM7351E"

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). If you really understand the consequences, at least use the current syntax and not the deprecated syntax. But no one can debug this without seeing the actual values you pass to your procedure. Despite the name, the parameter `@INPUTXML` seems to be just a plain string containing a path name - so the guess is that it is set to something you do not expect or handle correctly.